# Error while updating blitz 'Procedure [s p_Blitz], Line xxx Incorrect syntax near 'FROM A'

Tags: sp-blitz

I am trying to update Blitz to the latest version '7.95', @VersionDate = '20200506'. I get the following error

> Procedure [s p_Blitz], Line 5863Incorrect syntax near 'FROM A'.

The other error i am getting is

> Procedure [s p Blitz Cache]Line 4814 Invalid column name pages_k b.

Is their a fix for this error?

For anyone who is interested this is all of procedures that will break when attempting to update.

```
The module 'sp_AllNightLog' depends on the missing object 'master.dbo.DatabaseBackup'. The module will still be created; however, it cannot run successfully until the object exists.
The module 'sp_AllNightLog' depends on the missing object 'master.dbo.DatabaseBackup'. The module will still be created; however, it cannot run successfully until the object exists.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server [YourServerName], Procedure sp_Blitz, Line 5863
Incorrect syntax near 'FROMA'.
The module 'sp_BlitzFirst' depends on the missing object 'sp_BlitzWho'. The module will still be created; however, it cannot run successfully until the object exists.
```

Answer (score 1):

You're running the Install-All-Scripts.sql, which as you might guess from its name, installs all of the First Responder Kit scripts. However, some of those have dependencies on other third party objects.

If you're only trying to update sp_Blitz, either run just sp_Blitz.sql, or run the Install-Core-Blitz-No-Query-Store.sql.